# Save instance variable in a block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block, instance-variables

I cannot see the value of the instance variable @model when I call the lambda @description. Is this possible? I only see " is very good." when I call show_description.
Thanks in advance.

```
class Car
  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def description
    @description = lambda{yield}
  end

  def show_description
    @description.call
  end
end

c = Car.new("Ford")
c.description{"#{@model} is very good."}
puts c.show_description # => " is very good."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are saving the proc instance as `@description`, it is better to access that via a variable rather than using `yield`.

   ```
   def description &pr
     @description = pr
   end
   ```
2. You need to evaluate `@description` in the appropriate environment, i.e. within the instance of `Car`.

   ```
   def show_description
     instance_exec(&@description)
   end
   ```

With the fixes as above, it will work as you intended.

```
c = Car.new("Ford")
c.description{"#{@model} is very good."}
puts c.show_description
# => Ford is very good.
```

By the way, you can simplify `"#{@model} is very good."` to `"#@model is very good."`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes it is correct.. `cvar`, `gvar` abd `ivar` don't need `{..}`, only `#` is enough. **Example** - `>> @x = 12
=> 12
>> "I have #@x pens"
=> "I have 12 pens"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. A method from BasicObject, I didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

`c.description{"#{@model} is very good."}` wouldn't show you what you want. Point is, the block you passing, has access to the outside scope, where no variable `@model` is found, thus `@model` is `nil`. It is called *encapsulation*, due to this, outside world wouldn't be able to know/access directly the state of an object, in your case the object is `c`. Here object's *state* means value to the instance variables lies in object `c`. But using methods, you can read/update the states of the objects.

Thus do as `c.description{"#{c.model} is very good."}`.

Your code can be re-written as :

```
class Car
  attr_reader :model

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def description
    @description = yield
  end

  def show_description
    @description
  end
end

c = Car.new("Ford")
c.description{"#{c.model} is very good."}
puts c.show_description
# >> Ford is very good.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class Car
  attr_reader :model

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def description
    @description = lambda{yield}
  end

  def show_description
    @description.call
  end
end

c = Car.new("Ford")
c.description{"#{c.model} is very good."}
puts c.show_description #Ford is very good.
```